# Retrieve one entity from the database

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a class called `Page`:

```
case class Page(url: String)

object Page {
  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Page]
}
```

I am using Sorm to store it in the database:

```
import sorm._

object Db extends Instance(entities = Seq(Entity[Page]()), url="jdbc:h2:mem:test")
```

I would like to know how to retrieve one instance of this class from the database.
I tried by adding this to the routes file:

```
GET     /page/:pageId               controllers.Application.getPage(pageId)
```

Then, in the `Application` controller I am trying to retrieve it like this:

```
 def getPage(pageId: Int) = Action {
    val page = Db.query[pageId].fetch
  }
```

However, I am getting:

```
Cannot resolve symbol pageId
```

How can I retrieve a `Page` by its ID from the database?

Comment: It's possible that this error comes up because you left off the type signature for `pageId` in your routes file: `GET     /page/:pageId               controllers.Application.getPage(pageId: Int)` but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation here:
http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html

I realised that I need to make the query like this:

```
val page = Db.query[Page].whereEqual("id", pageId).fetch
```